# To post data to a link from ajax returning a seperate view

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, web

I am in a situation to post some data to another link and carry on the rest of the process in that controller.But when i do it in ajax i dont get the controllers view.I get only error from the ajax call.My ajax code is :

```
$.ajax({
       url  : "/xxx/yyy"
       method  : "POST",
       data : JSON.stringify(response.data),
       headers : 
       {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
       },
       success : function() 
       {
        alert("Success");
       },
       error : function(e)
       {
        alert("Error in page");
       }        
});
```

And my controller returns ModelAndView . I also tried returning String .But i get only the error messages (ie.Error in page) from the ajax call..Can anyone help me with it.?

Comment: And what's the error in "e"?

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in `url: "/xxx/yyy"` 
Comma is missing

after changes

```
url: "/xxx/yyy",
```

try this hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry i missed it here.The thing is that it goes inside the links controller too.But after going it doesnot show the view returned in that controller

Comment: Is it a proper url, you checked it properly?

Comment: Yeah it is a proper url

Comment: success : function(data) 
       {
        alert("Success" + data);
       }, try this

Comment: This is because you dont retrieving your data. so in success function use data to get data and alert it.

Comment: Actually i dont wanna return anything.I just want to do the process from the controller and return the view returned by that controller.